# Как организовать полноценный рабочий экземпляр монго дб на андроид

Tags: android, mongodb, cordova

Как организовать полноценный рабочий экземпляр монго дб на андроид со всеми фишками самой монги - как то геопоиск, междокументные ссылки и тд и тп, при использовании нативного апи.
Цель поиметь частичную реплику базы данных, синхронизируемую посредством wamp в реалтайме, и собственной синхронизационной процедуры для офлайн изменений.
Может быть кото-то реализовывал запуск монги через cordova или другой инструмент?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Не думаю, что возможно запустить полноценно рабочий экземпляр монги на Android. Его и в [списке](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/)  поддерживаемых платформ нет. Да и дело даже не в этом.

MongoDB не сможет нормально функционировать на подобных системах с таким маленьким объёмом доступной памяти для приложений.

Были, правда, [обсуждения](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1838) в своё время. Можно попробовать самим [собрать](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/iY3g0DAxQ_s) билд.

**UPD**: если вам не обязателен MongoDB, то можно использовать [Couchbase Lite](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android).